# How to retieve data for 2 different section in UICollectionView using MVC

Tags: ios, string, model-view-controller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hello everyone in my ios project I am using **MVC** for the data management of a `collectionView` which must show predefined times.

This `collectionView` has two sections and I need to show some specific data in one section and other data in another

I need help .. I have a struct model

```
struct TimeSelModel {
    let hour: String
    let minute: String
}
```

I recover data this way because I need to view some data in section 0 of my `collectionview` and other data in section 1

```
struct TimeSelData {
    
    static func dataSec (section: Int, _ completion: @escaping (Result <[TimeSelModel], Error>) -> ()) {
            if section == 0 {completion (.success (dataSec0))}
            else {completion (.success (dataSec1))}
    }
}
    
let dataSec0 = [
    TimeSelModel (hour: "09", minute: ": 30"),
    TimeSelModel (hour: "17", minute: ": 00")
]

let dataSec1 = [
    TimeSelModel (hour: "12", minute: ": 00"),
    TimeSelModel (hour: "19", minute: ": 00")
]
```

I use the data this way inside my controller

```
private var section: Int = 0

var data: [TimeSelModel] = []

private func fetchData() -> Void {
        
        TimeSelData.dataSec(section: section) {(result) in
            
            switch result {
            
            case.success (let data):
                
                self.data = date

            case.failure (let error): print (error.localizedDescription)

            }
        }
    }

    func collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        self.section = section
        return data.count}
    
    func collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell (withReuseIdentifier: TimeSelCell.cellID, for: indexPath) as! TimeSelCell
        
        cell.dataModel = data[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }
```

It doesn't work I don't get the right data for the sections of my `collectionView`... how can I achieve my goal of displaying different data for 2 different sections of a collectionView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an real multidimensional data model, this can be a nested array but a wrapper struct is preferable. If you need a section header name just uncomment the `name` member.

The `TimeSelData` struct is not needed, the escaping closure is pointless anyway

```
struct Section {
    // let name : String
    let models : [TimeSelModel]
}


var data: [Section] = []

private func fetchData() {
    data = [Section(models: dataSec0), Section(models: dataSec1)]
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
    
func collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data[section].models.count
}

func collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell (withReuseIdentifier: TimeSelCell.cellID, for: indexPath) as! TimeSelCell
    
    cell.dataModel = data[indexPath.section].models[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

Alternatively use [UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource), it's pretty powerful

Comment: Perfect thank you very much .. your suggestion works perfectly ...

I wanted to ask you ... In case I want to use the struct Section also for other controllers that don't need TimeSelModel data but other models how could I make the struct Section reusable for other Models and not just for TimeSelModel?

Comment: Make it generic `struct Section<T> { let models: [T] }`

Comment: var data: [Section] = [] 
at this point inserting a generic var data gives me an error

Comment: `var data : [Section<TimeSelModel>] = []`

Comment: Oh perfect ... in fact assigning the type to Section now works perfectly ... Thank you and I apologize for the many questions: D

Comment: excuse me if i need to retrieve a single value outside cellForItem for example in viewDidLoad how can I retrieve it according to your MVC implementation suggestion?

Comment: In a nutshell I should make a comparison between a string and the values ​​that TimeSelModel returns me and find among all the one equal to the comparison string

Comment: Please ask a new question and add an example what you are going to accomplish.

Comment: vadian.. i posted a new question for this question :D thanks a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66171636/compare-string-with-string-value-of-mvc