# Compare String with String value of MVC

Tags: ios, swift, string, model-view-controller, model

to view my data inside the cells of a `collectionView` I am using **MVC** architecture to keep the code clean

Now I have a class called `TimeSelModel` which handles has the model function

and it is structured in this way

```
struct Section<T> { 
   let model: [T] 
}
```

---

```
struct TimeSelModel {
    let hour: String
    let minute: String
}

let dataSec0 = [
    TimeSelModel(hour: "09", minute: ":30"),
    TimeSelModel(hour: "17", minute: ":00")
]

let dataSec1 = [
    TimeSelModel(hour: "12", minute: ":00"),
    TimeSelModel(hour: "19", minute: ":00")
]
```

---

I use this data in this way to use it in the `collectionView`

```
private var data: [Section<TimeSelModel>] = []

private func fetchData() -> Void {
        data = [Section(model: dataSec0), Section(model: dataSec1)]
    }

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int { data.count }
    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        data[section].model.count }
    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: TimeSelCell.cellID, for: indexPath) as! TimeSelCell
        
        cell.dataModel = data[indexPath.section].model[indexPath.item]
              
        return cell
    }
```

---

Now I need in a separate function to compare a `string` with the model values ​​I am using

For example I need to compare a `string` with value **"12"**  within the model values

```
let dataSec0 = [
        TimeSelModel (hour: "09", minute: ": 30"),
        TimeSelModel (hour: "17", minute: ": 00")
    ]
    
let dataSec1 = [
        TimeSelModel (hour: "12", minute: ": 00"),
        TimeSelModel (hour: "19", minute: ": 00")
    ]
```

What is the best and cleanest way to get this into my controller?

Comment: The question is quite unclear. Compare what? `hour` or `minute` or both? Compare equality or greater than or less than? Filter the objects or find the first one? What is the result supposed to be? Please edit the question and add more information.

Comment: @vadian Let me give a clearer example. In a nutshell I get the current time in String and the result is "17:00" . At this point I need to know if "17:00"  exists in my `collectionView` and select the cell that displays "17:00"

Comment: @vadian I don't know if the right way is to use for example `data[section].model[0].hour` I would like to know if there is a right way to solve the problem

Comment: My collectionView has 2 sections in both sections the times are divided according to a logic .. that's why Section was used to show data in a particular way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have one example in the question and then a different example in the comments here are 2 ways to get the index of a certain time in your `data` array.

```
let hourValue = "12"
if let index = data.firstIndex { section in section.model.contains { $0.hour == hourValue } } {
    let section = data[index]
    //...
}
```

and

```
let timeValue = "17:00"
if let index = data.firstIndex { section in section.model.contains { $0.time == timeValue } } {
    let section = data[index]
    //...
}
```

The last example uses a computed property that I added to `TimeSelModel`

```
struct TimeSelModel {
    let hour: String
    let minute: String

    var time: String {
        "\(hour):\(minute)"
    }
}
```

Note that it adds a ":" since I don't think it is a good idea to include the colon in the minute string as you do so instead of ":00" or ": 00" it should be just "00". (One could even argue that hour and minute should be integers but that is outside of the scope of this answer)

Also note that this answer is based on my interpretation of what the type `Section` is.

Comment: hello right now i'm feeding my son  forgive me if i haven't given you any feedback on your answer yet ... as soon as i finish i try to understand your question and maybe if i have some problem i can contact you ?? I'm sorry again and thank you for your answer .. very often I still have a lot of difficulties in understanding how to set up my code so sorry if my questions sometimes seem stupid  I will contact you as soon as possible

Comment: So I'm implementing your suggestion it seems to work but I have only one problem ... it always returns me the first value of the array .. surely I'm doing something wrong .. maybe if you have some time I could explain better in chat the code to avoid creating too many comments here in the question

Comment: On the contrary, I correct myself .. it does not give me back any value but surely as I said before the problem is me and not your suggestion

Comment: In short, with your suggestion I receive the number of items in my section .. instead I'm trying to find the item that hosts the value "17:00" in order to select the cell

Comment: Also I wanted to communicate what "Section" is  `struct Section<T> { let model: [T] }`

Comment: i updated my question with "Section".. With the `struct` **Section** I can determine in which section I have to show my correct data in `collectionView`

Comment: it seems to work with `if let index = data[section].model.firstIndex(where: { $0.time == timeValue } ) { selectItem(item: index, section: section)}`

Answer (score 0):

Strings are comparable like `myTime.hour < "12"` by their unicode value.

This means `"0" < "1"` is true

But `"2" < "12"` is false

In your case, you should compare strings with the Foundation's function https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1408732-compare
and give the `options` parameter `.numeric` : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1415530-numeric

```swift
switch myTime.hour.compare("12", options: [.numeric]) {
    case .orderedAscending:
        // myTime.hour < "12"

    case .orderedSame:
        // myTime.hour == "12"

    case .orderedDescending:
        // myTime.hour > "12"
}
```

But I would recommend changing your model by using Int or TimeInterval and use a function that transforms your model to readable string you want

Comment: I needed to understand based on my example

Comment: So the problem is not just comparing string, but also retrieving a model, retrieving a value, using MVC pattern, using UIKit, using swift... not the good question IMO

Comment: In the question I clearly specified that I needed to compare a string with a string of an MVC model